# Sending and Receiving mail through php contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

Recently, I have purchased a domain and hosting. I've also created a webpage having contact form in it. I want when the user wrote something in textarea of contact form and clicks **submit** then that message is sended to my gmail account and so that i can reply also to those messages. I've also used this script to do so but its not working.

This is **sendemail.php** file

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'raunakhajela@gmail.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

This is my contact form code in **index.php**

```
<div class="contact" id="contact">
            <div class="container-3x">

                <div class="block-header"> <!-- Blocks Header -->
                    <h2 class="title">Contact Us</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="block-content"> <!-- Blocks Content -->

                    <form action="sendemailphp" method="post" class="trigger-form-animate">
                        <input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name *" />
                        <input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" />
                        <input type="text" value="" id="website" name="website" placeholder="Website *" />
                        <textarea type="text" value="" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message *" ></textarea>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                        <button>Submit Message</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

I've also tried "**http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2012/06/connect-your-website-email-address-to.html**" this tutorial but its not working. Unable to find "**Send through Gmail (easier to set up)**" this option in gmail on adding another accounts windoww.

How can i do that?? Plzz hlp

Comment: Suppressing errors doesn't help your cause using `@` and not [**checking for them**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in the first place.

Comment: yes, remove `@` and also use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `display_errors(1);` And let's `var_dump($success);` Is it true or false?

Comment: guys i don't know much about php, just downloaded evento template from http://shapebootstrap.net/item/evento-free-music-event-template/  having sendemail.php file in it. I just replaced email address to my email , used this file on another template i've created and uploaded file onto my server but when i tried submitting message then it just displayed "success" but haven't received any message on my gmail account.

Comment: This `action="sendemailphp"` are you sure you didn't meant `action="sendemail.php"`? In doing that, it worked for me. Tested `{"type":"success","message":"Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you "}` <= response.

Comment: sry guys it's just syntax error while writing this ques but yes i've tried action="sendemail.php". Yet it didn't worked out...

Comment: The only thing is that, you don't have a `subject` form element which may explain why and mail might be sent to Spam instead. As in `name="subject"`. Either add one of replace `$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));` with `$subject = "Form submission";`

Comment: You could also add `<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form submission">` to your form. Either this or what I've outlined just above will work.

Comment: ohk thanxx fred bro...will try this if didn't worked out will mention in comment...

Comment: @RaunakHajela You're welcome Raunak. I've posted an answer below which you can have a look at, with some additional information.

Comment: fred can i get your email so that i can contact you for asking future ques..??

Comment: i checked your profile but der z not any messgae option so that i can contact you...

Comment: Sure there is, click the "Say Hello" link. Btw, you do know how the Stack system works right? If an answer was given and it resolved the problem, you tick the checkmark next to the answer till it turns green. Just thought you might like to know that, because if you ask many questions but do not accept any, future answerers may be reluctant to give "answers". ;)

Comment: So, is your code working now?

Comment: Guys both solutions are not working. Now what to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a named `subject` form element which may explain why mail is failing and may very well be sent to Spam instead.

For example: `<input type="text" name="subject">`. Either add one of replace.

You will however need to make sure that this is filled out using a conditional statement
(*see further below for an example*).

```
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
```

with

```
$subject = "Form submission";
```

You could also add this instead to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form submission">
```

Either this or what I've outlined just above will work.

Many Email clients will either send mail to Spam or reject it altogether if a "subject" is missing, which is clearly missing from your code.

Checking if subject has been filled example:

```
if(isset($_POST['subject']) && !empty($_POST['subject'])){

// do someting

}
```

Comment: sry bro ds z not working... :-(

Comment: @RaunakHajela Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus change `$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');` to `$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');` remove the @ symbol. While removing all @ symbols in your code.

Comment: do i have to remove @ from name,email & message as that of subject??

Comment: in ds case also its not working. Didn't receive any email yet in my gmail account

Comment: @RaunakHajela I would contact your hosting company then, make sure `mail()` is available for you to use. Plus, check your Spam box. I've tested your code with no problems on my end and sent to my Gmail account without a hitch. Maybe your host is on a blacklist, it's very very hard to say why it's failing at this point.

Comment: I got domain and hosting from bigrock.in. I got multi-domain linux hosting.

Comment: @RaunakHajela As I said, contact tech support. There's nothing else I can do or say to be of further help.

Comment: ohk den will check it...anwz thanxx bro :-)

Comment: bro did you have any tutorial describing about complete php contact form which works correctly for receiving and sending emails for this task...any link or something??

Comment: @RaunakHajela I don't keep links per se, but there are many you can find on Google by using "php send mail form".

Comment: ohk will try and contact you for further queries...hv a nyc day.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this,both will work

```
 <?php
  $to = "usermailid@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Welcome to";
    $message = " Hi $username,<br /><br />
    Thank you for signing up with us.<br />

    Thanks <br />";
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <yourmailid@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if($mail)   
    {
    $to = "admin@gmail.com";

    $subject = "Following Customer Signed Up";
    $message = " $username,Customer is signed up with us,<br /><br />
    Customer Details:<br />First Name:$firstname<br/>Last Name:$lastname<br/>Email:$email<br/>
    Phone:$phone<br/>Zip Code:$zip<br/>Message:$message_cust<br/><br/><br/>
    Thanks <br />";
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <yourmailid@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: sry bro ds z also not working... n by the way what is test@gmail.com and admi@gmail.com ??

Comment: Dude i have given those mail id's for a sample purpose.you should change them with valid email id's while you are testing the code.

Comment: bro wat i mean is test@gmail.com is email written in text field or some random email..??